# Delete files if the user uninstall the application in Blackberry

Tags: file, blackberry, uninstallation, delete-file, file-connection

I need to store some data in my Blackberry application so I'm using files, I'm storing these files in the internal memory of the device,  but if I uninstalled the application I need these files to be removed too.
Is there a way to store the files in the same path of the application package , or any other way to delete them if the application was uninstalled?

This is the path which I'm using:

```
    try {
    fileconn = (FileConnection) Connector.open("file:///store/home/user/data.txt");
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

What kind of data are you storing? If you can store the data in the app's PersistentStore instead, it will automatically be deleted when the app is uninstalled.

Comment: I'm caching a lot of data, Xml files, so i need to keep them in the internal memory,i found some code about CodeModuleListener, but i did not figure out how to use it.